# How to override a function in Woocommerce WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT Class

Tags: php, wordpress, class, woocommerce, overriding

I would like to override the function [`search_orders()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/data-stores/class-wc-order-data-store-cpt.php#L488-L545) in Woocommerce `WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT` Class located in `includes/data-stores/class-wc-order-data-store-cpt.php`

Here is that function source code that I need to override:

```
/**
 * Search order data for a term and return ids.
 *
 * @param  string $term
 * @return array of ids
 */
public function search_orders( $term ) {
    global $wpdb;

    /**
     * Searches on meta data can be slow - this lets you choose what fields to search.
     * 3.0.0 added _billing_address and _shipping_address meta which contains all address data to make this faster.
     * This however won't work on older orders unless updated, so search a few others (expand this using the filter if needed).
     * @var array
     */

    $term = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $term); //  <===  <===  <=== HERE

    $search_fields = array_map( 'wc_clean', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', array(
        '_billing_address_index',
        '_shipping_address_index',
        '_billing_last_name',
        '_billing_email',
    ) ) );
    $order_ids = array();

    if ( is_numeric( $term ) ) {
        $order_ids[] = absint( $term );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $search_fields ) ) {
        $order_ids = array_unique( array_merge(
            $order_ids,
            $wpdb->get_col(
                $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT DISTINCT p1.post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} p1 WHERE p1.meta_value LIKE '%%%s%%'", $wpdb->esc_like( wc_clean( $term ) ) ) . " AND p1.meta_key IN ('" . implode( "','", array_map( 'esc_sql', $search_fields ) ) . "')"
            ),
            $wpdb->get_col(
                $wpdb->prepare( "
                    SELECT order_id
                    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as order_items
                    WHERE order_item_name LIKE '%%%s%%'
                    ",
                    $wpdb->esc_like( wc_clean( $term ) )
                )
            )
        ) );
    }

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_results', $order_ids, $term, $search_fields );
}
```

**I just want to add this add the beginning of the function**

```
$term = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $term);
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use available `woocommerce_shop_order_search_results` filter hook located at the [end of the function](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/data-stores/class-wc-order-data-store-cpt.php#L544), that will allow to override that method:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_results', 'custom_shop_order_search_results_filter', 10, 3 );
function custom_shop_order_search_results_filter( $order_ids, $term, $search_fields ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $term      = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $term); //  <===  <===  <===  Your change

    $order_ids = array();

    if ( is_numeric( $term ) ) {
        $order_ids[] = absint( $term );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $search_fields ) ) {
        $order_ids = array_unique(
            array_merge(
                $order_ids,
                $wpdb->get_col(
                    $wpdb->prepare(
                        "SELECT DISTINCT p1.post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} p1 WHERE p1.meta_value LIKE %s AND p1.meta_key IN ('" . implode( "','", array_map( 'esc_sql', $search_fields ) ) . "')", // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
                        '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( wc_clean( $term ) ) . '%'
                    )
                ),
                $wpdb->get_col(
                    $wpdb->prepare(
                        "SELECT order_id
                        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as order_items
                        WHERE order_item_name LIKE %s",
                        '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( wc_clean( $term ) ) . '%'
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }
    return $order_ids
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested, it should works.